# Как правильно составить запрос xpath?

Tags: c#, html, xpath, htmlagilitypack

Использую htmlagilitypack. Необходимо вытащить ссылку и перейти по ней

```html
Страница со списком товаров

<li class="result__item cr-result__full  g-box_lseparator cr-state_ee_sent">
  <img src="https://www.site.ru/img/tmp/brends/gefest.png" class="result__brand">
  <dl>
    <dt class="result__root">
            <span class="result__tools">
                <span class=" g-price result__price cr-price__in"><span data-code="22383" data-name="Кухонная плита Gefest 1200 С7 К8" data-price="288.00" class="g-item-data j-item-data j-item-data22383 ">288,00</span><span class="g-price__unit result__priceunit">руб.</span></span>    <span class="result__tools-item"><span class="g-status result__status cr-status__in">На складе</span></span>
                <span class="b-reviews-rate result__tools-item"><span class="reviews-rate cr-reviews-rate" style="width:100%;"></span></span>    <span class="result__tools-item"><form class="j-to_basket" method="post" action="/to_basket/?item=22383&amp;special=0&amp;price=288.00"><button class="g-button g-buybtn result__buybtn cr-buybtn__in j-ga_track" data-ga_action="add_to_cart" data-ga_on="click" data-ga_label="result_buybtn" data-ga_category="Ordering">В корзину</button></form></span>
                <div class="result__installment">Рассрочка без переплат до&nbsp;12&nbsp;мес.</div>
                <span class="result__tools-item"><a href="/cookers/compare/?item=22383" class="compare__link g-pseudo_href j-compare" rel="nofollow">Добавить в сравнение</a></span>
            </span>

            <span class="g-code">код 22.383</span>
            <a href="https://www.site.ru/cookers/gefest_120078.html" class="result__link j-ga_track" data-ga_action="GoToItem" data-ga_on="click" data-ga_label="catalog" data-ga_category="Navigation">
                <span class="result__img">
                    <img src="https://www.site.ru/img/galleries/22/383/preview/gefest_120078_32357.jpeg" class="" alt="Кухонная плита Gefest 1200 С7 К8 - ">
                </span>
                <span class="result__name">Кухонная плита Gefest 1200 С7 К8</span>
            </a>
        </dt>

    <dd class="result__desc ">
      <div class="result__attrs">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="result__attr_var  cr-result__attr_odd">Тип варочной панели</td>
              <td class="result__attr_val  cr-result__attr_odd">газовая</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="result__attr_var ">Тип духового шкафа</td>
              <td class="result__attr_val ">газовый</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="result__attr_var  cr-result__attr_odd">Количество конфорок/зон нагрева</td>
              <td class="result__attr_val  cr-result__attr_odd">4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="result__attr_var ">Объём</td>
              <td class="result__attr_val ">63&nbsp;л</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="result__attr_var  cr-result__attr_odd">Автоматические программы приготовления</td>
              <td class="result__attr_val  cr-result__attr_odd">нет</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="result__attr_var ">Общая мощность</td>
              <td class="result__attr_val ">8100&nbsp;Вт</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="result__attr_var  cr-result__attr_odd">Управление</td>
              <td class="result__attr_val  cr-result__attr_odd">механическое</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </dd>
  </dl>
</li>

... Страница с товаром

<div class="tabs__content">
  <div class="b-info cr-info-descr" itemprop="description">
    <p>Сопла в комплект плиты не входят.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="b-info cr-info-attrs">
    <div class="b-attrs columns__nowrap">
      <div class="attr__header">Основные характеристики</div>
      <div class="attr_item">
        <span class="attr__name">
                    Тип варочной панели
                </span>
        <span class="attr__value">газовая</span>
      </div>
      <div class="attr_item">
        <span class="attr__name">
                    Тип духового шкафа
                </span>
        <span class="attr__value">газовый</span>
      </div>
      <div class="attr_item">
        <span class="attr__name">
                    Рабочая поверхность
                </span>
        <span class="attr__value">эмаль</span>
      </div>
      <div class="attr_item">
        <span class="attr__name">
                    Цвет
                </span>
        <span class="attr__value">белый</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="g-box_lseparator">
    <div class="g-notice">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```html
<li class="result__item cr-result__full  g-box_lseparator cr-state_ee_sent">
  <img src="https://www.site.ru/img/tmp/brends/gefest.png" class="result__brand">
  <dl>
    <dt class="result__root">
            <span class="result__tools">
                <span class=" g-price result__price cr-price__in"><span data-code="22383" data-name="Кухонная плита Gefest 1200 С7 К8" data-price="288.00" class="g-item-data j-item-data j-item-data22383 ">288,00</span><span class="g-price__unit result__priceunit">руб.</span></span>    <span class="result__tools-item"><span class="g-status result__status cr-status__in">На складе</span></span>
                <span class="b-reviews-rate result__tools-item"><span class="reviews-rate cr-reviews-rate" style="width:100%;"></span></span>    <span class="result__tools-item"><form class="j-to_basket" method="post" action="/to_basket/?item=22383&amp;special=0&amp;price=288.00"><button class="g-button g-buybtn result__buybtn cr-buybtn__in j-ga_track" data-ga_action="add_to_cart" data-ga_on="click" data-ga_label="result_buybtn" data-ga_category="Ordering">В корзину</button></form></span>
                <div class="result__installment">Рассрочка без переплат до&nbsp;12&nbsp;мес.</div>
                <span class="result__tools-item"><a href="/cookers/compare/?item=22383" class="compare__link g-pseudo_href j-compare" rel="nofollow">Добавить в сравнение</a></span>
            </span>

            <span class="g-code">код 22.383</span>
            <a href="https://www.site.ru/cookers/gefest_120078.html" class="result__link j-ga_track" data-ga_action="GoToItem" data-ga_on="click" data-ga_label="catalog" data-ga_category="Navigation">
                <span class="result__img">
                    <img src="https://www.site.ru/img/galleries/22/383/preview/gefest_120078_32357.jpeg" class="" alt="Кухонная плита Gefest 1200 С7 К8 - ">
                </span>
                <span class="result__name">Кухонная плита Gefest 1200 С7 К8</span>
            </a>
        </dt>

    <dd class="result__desc ">
      <div class="result__attrs">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="result__attr_var  cr-result__attr_odd">Тип варочной панели</td>
              <td class="result__attr_val  cr-result__attr_odd">газовая</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="result__attr_var ">Тип духового шкафа</td>
              <td class="result__attr_val ">газовый</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="result__attr_var  cr-result__attr_odd">Количество конфорок/зон нагрева</td>
              <td class="result__attr_val  cr-result__attr_odd">4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="result__attr_var ">Объём</td>
              <td class="result__attr_val ">63&nbsp;л</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="result__attr_var  cr-result__attr_odd">Автоматические программы приготовления</td>
              <td class="result__attr_val  cr-result__attr_odd">нет</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="result__attr_var ">Общая мощность</td>
              <td class="result__attr_val ">8100&nbsp;Вт</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="result__attr_var  cr-result__attr_odd">Управление</td>
              <td class="result__attr_val  cr-result__attr_odd">механическое</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </dd>
  </dl>
</li>

...
```

Comment: оффтоп, конечно, но стоит подумать об использовании чего-то менее монструозного чем HtmlAgilityPack, например, [F# Data](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/) .

Comment: Так вы покажите свой неправильный xpath.

Comment: В общем то начал я вот так, попытался загрузить список товаров  var offerNodeList = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id='j-result-page-1']/li[1]");   но это дело вернуло null